# Doubt in high school permutations result of identical items

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations

> Find the total number of proper factors of $7875$

For solving this question I used a result of identical **Permutations**:

*The total number of selections of some or all out of $p+q+r$ items where $p$ are alike of one kind, $q$ are alike of second kind and rest are alike of third kind is* $[(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)]-1$.

This formula works perfectly fine for this question as $(2+1)(3+1)(1+1)-1$ = $23$

But,I can't solve question (2) by this formula

> $(2)$The number of positive integral solutions of  $abc=   30$  is

It's correct answer is $27$

But according to formula it's answer will be $(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)-1 = 7$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I had to remove your bounding box since it did not fit the space reserved for questions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sir please answer my question

Comment: Why do you think this formula applies to the first question? Why do you think it applies to the second question?

Comment: @DavidK according to me,this formula selects one or many numbers out of given numbers so I could use this formula .E.g It can select 1.2.15 as well as 1.1.30 etc

Comment: @DavidK Am I wrong?

Comment: I do not see 2 or 15 anywhere in the formula $abc=30.$ I think even in the first case you may just be getting lucky that the answer happens to come out to the one in the answer key. Unless you have a logical sequence of reasons why something should be so, you cannot know whether you have good answers, lucky answers, or wrong answers.

Comment: @DavidK No, sir it's not a lucky answer I had applied this formula over 10 question each time I got correct answer.You could for e.g 2160,1279 etc.

Comment: By the way, I think I know why you thought you could find three kinds of item in the number $7875,$ and you would be almost correct, but also a bit lucky that one mistake canceled another. It seems you _are_ lucky that someone gave you ten questions in a row that all get solved exactly the same way. That's just luck, because you see that as soon as they gave you one a little different you have no idea how to solve it. So please take a step back and edit your question to show _all_ the steps of your thinking, not just the formula applied without a reason given.

Comment: The number of proper factors of $30$ (which is $7$) is an *entirely* different question than the number of solutions for $a,b,c$ so that $abc=0$.

Comment: It's a different question.  You aren't asked how many factors $30$ has, but how many factorizations of the form $abc$.  Note that $2\cdot3\cdot5$ is one such factorization;  $3\cdot2\cdot5$ is another.

Comment: *How* did you apply the formula?  The $7$ proper factors of $30$ are $2,3,6,5,10,15, 30$ (which you can get by the formula).  But how would you use that to find solutions to $abc=30$.  How would you go from saying "3 is a factor of 30" to saying "a = 3; b=2; c=5 is a solution to abc=30" (or "a=1; b=3; c=10 is a solution").  What relationship do the factors of 30 have with the solutions to abc =30.  They certainly are not one to one.  So we do you think the answer to one question is the answer to the other question.

Comment: @fleablood I just realized how stupid I am.Thanks sir for helping me!!!

Comment: You're not stupid. You're learning mathematics. It's all part of the learning process. Feel good about the fact that you made progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different types of questions involved here.

The formula you used works for determining the number of proper factors of a positive integer with three distinct prime factors.  If $$n = p_1^pp_2^qp_3^r$$ then each factor of $n$ has the form $$m = p_1^{j}p_2^{k}p^{l}$$ where $j \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, p\}$, $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, q\}$, and $l \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, r\}$.  Hence, $j$ can be chosen in $p + 1$ ways, $k$ can be chosen in $q + 1$ ways, and $l$ can be chosen in $r + 1$ ways.  Thus, $n$ has 
$$(p + 1)(q + 1)(r + 1)$$
factors, of which $1$ is proper.  Hence, $n$ has 
$$(p + 1)(q + 1)(r + 1) - 1$$
proper factors.

The first question is asking for the number of proper factors of $7875$.  To determine this, we first factor $7875$ into primes.
\begin{align*}
7875 & = 3 \cdot 2625\\
     & = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 875\\
     & = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 175\\
     & = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 35\\
     & = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 7\\
     & = 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7
\end{align*}
Each factor of $7875$ has the form $3^a5^b7^c$, where $a \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, $b \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, and $c \in \{0, 1\}$.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 18$ factors of $7875$ and $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 - 1 = 17$ proper factors of $7875$.

Since $30 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, it has $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 8 - 1 = 7$ proper factors.

The second question is asking for the number of ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $abc = 30$.  This is not the same thing.

In this question, each prime must appear once among the three factors. If we write
\begin{align*}
a & = 2^{x_1}3^{y_1}5^{z_1}\\
b & = 2^{x_2}3^{y_2}5^{z_2}\\
c & = 2^{x_3}3^{y_3}5^{z_3}
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 1 \tag{1}\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 1 \tag{2}\\
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 & = 1 \tag{3}
\end{align}
since each prime appears once in the factorization of $30$. Equations 1, 2, and 3 are equations in the nonnegative integers, each of which has three solutions, depending on which of the three variables is equal to $1$.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 27$ such ordered triples.